# Accessing Calendar API on using Plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a program to take a work schedule from a website and put into Google calendar. I've been attempting to figure out the code for OAuth, but it seems I can't use their API. I found this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_javascript but I can't get it working. It tells me it doesn't understand any of the commands I'm trying to run.

If you know of an extension doing something like this I would like to look at the source code and hopefully figure this out.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project! If you want help tho, why don't you post the exact error message you're getting and the code that's causing it? That way the community can actually help you.

Comment: I am not able to access calendar. After accessing calendar I can do further things.. Please give me suggestion means How should ?